# put "source /etc/profile" in /etc/bash.bashrc and unable to open terminal window in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, bashrc, bash-profile

I put "source /etc/profile" in /etc/bash.bashrc and unable to open terminal window in ubuntu 16.04, and now, whenever I try to open a terminal window, it closes after a few seconds. During those few seconds, there is no prompt and it does not except commands.

My /etc/bash.bashrc looks like

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

source /etc/profile
alias login="sudo login"

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.

    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

This is my /etc/profile

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
export NODE_REPL_HISTORY=""
unset HISTFILE
set +o history
alias login="sudo login"

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

I am 99% sure that the reason the terminal closes is the infinite loop I accidentally created, where one calls the other and the other calls the one.

What can I do?

Comment: well, good (or maybe bad) news are that you are right, you are calling `. /etc/bash.bashrc` from `/etc/profile` vice-versa... is the Ubuntu virtual or physical? e.g. cloud or hardware?

Comment: @Christopher It is a physical computer in my possession, not on the cloud.

Comment: What happens if you type the Ctrl+C character during those few seconds?

Comment: Switch to the console mode then remove the added line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed the infinite loop. The shell reads `/etc/profile`, sees that it needs to read `/etc/bash.bashrc` and does so, sees that it needs to read `/etc/profile` and does so, etc. Eventually the shell decides that it's recursing too deeply and gives up.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while the shell is still working its way through the startup files. You'll get a prompt.

Then remove both the inclusion of `/etc/bash.bashrc` in `/etc/profile` and the inclusion of `/etc/profile` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Those files have different roles:

- `/etc/profile` is read at login time and does things like setting environment variables. It is often executed by a shell other than bash.
- `/etc/bash.bashrc` is a configuration file of bash, only for interactive sessions. It should contain things like aliases and prompts. Bash loads it when you run bash in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a live-usb with any distro that you like. Turn on your computer from the liveusb and then mount the partition where is your `/` something like

`mount /dev/sdX /mnt`

`/mnt` would be in your liveISO.

then just edit with nano, vim, or any other text editor your configuration and erase one the those lines.

Then `umount` your disk and restart the computer, it should work.

Comment: Or just bootstrap the existing system into rescue mode or emergency mode.